# How to tell if element is currently actively scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I'd like to stop certain things from happening while an element is being scrolled.
Scrolling may start when the `mouse wheel` / `mouse pad` is used, but it may also happen from a `scrollIntoView()` being called.
Is there a way to tell if an element is currently being scrolled directly from that element?

Comment: So you mean not the page itself but a child element within?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that helps you to detect scrolling with debounce and you can start to invoke any function after a set timer.

```js
let timeOut;
function debounce(delay) {
  console.log("It's rolling!");
  clearTimeout(timeOut);
  timeOut= setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("It's stopped!");
  }, delay);
}

document.querySelector("#scrollable").addEventListener('scroll',(function() {
  debounce(200);
}));
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="scrollable">In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.
<br><br>
'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'</div>
```